# SWI Prolog func pack

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I've got a prolog source file that allows me to use the `($)/2` meta predicate fine, but when I convert it to a module as follows, I get syntax errors wherever `$` used to work:

```
:- module('mymodule', [mypred1/2, mypred2/3, ($)/2]).
:- use_module(library(func)).
```

I've tried `reexport` as well, to no avail.

So doing things like `X is mypred1$"something"` gives me a syntax error. However, removing the `:- module(...` line from the source file fixes the issue.

How do I get `$` functioning properly within a module?

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears when you use a custom infix operator `($)/2` and introduce module "boundaries".

When implementing [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord.html), Ulrich Neumerkel faced the same problem!
For a SWI-specific fix, check out and study [lambda.pl](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl)—it starts with:

```
:- module(lambda, [(^)/3, (^)/4, (^)/5, (^)/6, (^)/7, (^)/8, (^)/9, (^)/10,
                   (\)/1, (\)/2, (\)/3, (\)/4, (\)/5, (\)/6, (\)/7, (\)/8,
                   (+\)/2, (+\)/3, (+\)/4, (+\)/5, (+\)/6, (+\)/7, (+\)/8, (+\)/9,
                   op(201,xfx,+\)]).
```

*That's it!*

Also, read the SWI manual on [module/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=module/2) and you're good to go!